# Efficient binary-search

Tags: c++, binary-search

Out of the two different implementation of binary-search, which one is more efficient and why?

In general binary-search divide a sorted array to two, compare the target entry with operator < or > against the two divided part of array, and keep iterating until finished or found the target entry.

```
int a[8] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11};
```

1.

```
while ( size > 1)
{
    mid = low + (size/2);
    if (a[mid] > find)
    {
       size = mid - low;
    }
    else
    {
        size = size - (mid - low);
        low = mid;
    }
}
```

2.

```
while (low <= size)
{
    mid = (low + size)/2;
    if (a[mid] < find)
    {
        low = mid + 1;
    }
    else if (a[mid] > find)
    {
        size = mid - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    } 
}
```

While searching 6, the first one, iterate as,

```
mid = 4 size = 4 low = 0
mid = 2 size = 2 low = 2
mid = 3 size = 1 low = 3
5
```

and the second one does one iterate more and taking next entry.

```
mid = 4 size = 3 low = 0
mid = 1 size = 3 low = 2
mid = 2 size = 3 low = 3
mid = 3 size = 3 low = 4
7
```

Which one is efficient?

Comment: The standard library has a nice, readily available, efficient [binary search algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search). Use it already. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I know the availability of wheel and <algorithm>. The question is intended as KB.

Comment: Measure both, because it can depend on the data. If I have to guess, I'd say the first version is faster, because it has one less branch. But maybe it doesn't matter too much, as the `if (a[mid] > find)` branch is almost always will be true, can be easily predicted.

Comment: @meAbab And "KB" is *what*?

Comment: search for "Algorithm complexity and Big O notation", often with a table of:
" Algorithm Best case Expected"